# reduce every element of the array to zero

Tags: algorithm

i have an array consist of only non negative integers. now i want to reduce every element to zero. the only operation allowed is 'decrement each element in the range i,j by 1' cost of each such operation is 1. now question is how to find the minimum number of such operation that can transform this array to all zero element array.

```
example: [1 2 3 0]
--->[0 1 2 0] (decrement all element in the range 0 to 2)
--->[0 0 1 0] (----------------------------range 1 to 2)
--->[0 0 0 0] (----------------------------range 2 to 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a duplicate, but I can find no evidence of that, so I'll answer instead.

In every optimal solution, there exists no pair of operations [a, b) and [b, c), since we could unite them as [a, c). There exists, moreover, an optimal solution that is laminar, namely, for each pair of operations, their scopes are nested or disjoint, but not partially overlapping. This is because we can convert operations on [a, c) and [b, d) to [a, d) and [b, c).

Subject to the latter restriction, there is only one optimal strategy up to permuting the operations, derived by repeatedly decreasing a maximal nonzero interval. (Proof by induction: consider the decrease operation whose interval argument is leftmost and maximal among other interval arguments. By the leftmost assumption, this interval must include the leftmost nonzero. If it excludes a contiguous nonzero element to its right, then how could that element get decreased? Not by an interval that starts to the left (that wouldn't be laminar) and not by an interval that starts with that element (that wouldn't be optimal), so not at all.)

All that we have to do algorithmically is to construct this optimal solution. In Python:

```
cost = 0
stackheight = 0
for x in lst:
    cost += max(x - stackheight, 0)
    stackheight = x
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few small examples, and so far I haven't found any where a simple greedy algorithm does not produce the best solution. The approach I used is:

```
loop
    find largest element
    if largest element is zero
        break
    expand interval with non-zero values left and right around largest, until zero/boundary is encountered
    decrement values in this interval
```

I found cases where there are other solutions with the same number of steps, but not better. For example, with this algorithm:

```
2 3 1 2 3
1 2 0 1 2
0 1 0 1 2
0 1 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

So that's 5 steps. This ties it, with a different sequence:

```
2 3 1 2 3
1 2 1 2 3
1 2 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

I would be interested in seeing counter-examples where this strategy does not produce a best solution.

Comment: My answer proves correct a class of greedy algorithms that includes this one (any nonzero element, not just the largest, will do).